# How to query review requests by user, using Github's v4 GraphQL API?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

Given a user's id, I want to get all pull requests where they are a requested reviewer.

The following won't work as it only allows me to get pull requests *opened* by that user:

```
query {
  node(id: "$user") {
    ... on User {
      pullRequests(first: 100) {
        nodes {
          reviewRequests(first: 100) {
            nodes {
              requestedReviewer {
                ... on User {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get username from the user id and perform a search with [`review-requested`](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-pull-requests-by-review-status) to match a user requested for review :

get username :

```graphql
{
  node(id: "MDQ6VXNlcjk2OTQ3") {
    ... on User {
      login
    }
  }
}
```

get open PR where user is review requested :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "type:pr state:open review-requested:refack", type: ISSUE, first: 100) {
    issueCount
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      startCursor
    }
    edges {
      node {
        ... on PullRequest {
          repository {
            nameWithOwner
          }
          number
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can define the query string as a variable, [try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=query%20(%24query%3A%20String!)%20%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%24query%2C%20type%3A%20ISSUE%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20issueCount%0A%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20startCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20PullRequest%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20number%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&variables=%7B%0A%20%20%22query%22%3A%20%22type%3Apr%20state%3Aopen%20review-requested%3Arefack%22%0A%7D)

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.